# ADB claims that app is not installed when uninstalling and that it is installed when installing

Tags: adb, 7.0-nougat, installation, uninstallation

Gboard kept crashing when trying to open the settings, so I wanted to uninstall and reinstall it. Google Play Store kept giving me the error code 910, the advice for that was installing it with ADB.

The command

```
adb install -r /home/fabian/Downloads/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin_7.9.7.230658658-release-armeabi-v7a-26790713_minAPI21\(armeabi-v7a\)\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk
```

gives me the output

```
Failed to install /home/fabian/Downloads/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin_7.9.7.230658658-release-armeabi-v7a-26790713_minAPI21(armeabi-v7a)(nodpi)_apkmirror.com.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install com.google.android.inputmethod.latin without first uninstalling package running as com.android.inputmethod.latin]
```

This is weird, since with the `-r` flag it should have no problem with an app that is already installed. Apart from that, it is not installed, I checked the app list, the `/system/app` directory, as well as `/data/data`. And when I run

```
adb uninstall com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
```

, the output is:

```
Exception occurred while dumping:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
    at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4134)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:18419)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackage(PackageManagerService.java:15836)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:888)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:792)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:118)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:94)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:18682)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:468)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:367)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2387)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3150)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

So what can I do to install GBoard again?

<sub>Fairphone 2, Android 7.1.2, "Fairphone Open", root enabled</sub>

Comment: Did the app come pre-installed?

Comment: @esQmo Right, important detail: I flashed openGApps, because "FairphonOpen" has no Google Apps in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the package wasn't properly uninstalled : This happens usually if you delete the APK from */data/app* or */system/app* or */system/priv-app* instead of uninstalling the app. That is why probably the adb uninstall command isn't working.

Maybe you can try reinstalling the app again after rebooting your phone?
Tip: If this is the only keyboard app on your phone, it would be better if you install another keyboard app just as a backup before rebooting (especially if you have a text lock screen password).

If it still doesn't work after rebooting, try uninstalling the app only for the current user and then reinstall it from the play store.

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
```

Also, if possible, please also share the output of this command

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
```

(Sorry, I am a new member and do not have commenting permissions yet; that is why I have to mention it here.)

Comment: Output of the first command: `Failure [not installed for 0]` Output of the second command: `Renamed packages:
  com.google.android.inputmethod.latin,com.android.inputmethod.latin


Dexopt state:
  Unable to find package: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin


Compiler stats:
  Unable to find package: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin` And yes, I did reboot.

Comment: Oh, I just remembered that the app that I used to uninstall GBoard had made a backup of it! I restored that backup and it actually worked. Now I'm back at the state where GBoard crashes every time I open the settings.

Comment: Afterwards, uninstalling and reinstalling worked. This doesn't solve the question, but I don't need an answer anymore.

Comment: I still suspect that my initial statement was right. Maybe the app that you used to uninstall GBoard didn't uninstall it properly. It probably just deleted the app APK from its system applications folder, so the GBoard app didn't get properly unregistered from the system.    Then, when you restored the backup, the app probably put back the APK from where it had deleted it earlier and hence it might have started working again.

Comment: So you mean that just putting the APK file into the right folder would have solved it as well?

Comment: Probably. But you had also mentioned in your question that you hadn't found anything in your system apps folder. Maybe the uninstaller had deleted the folder?

Comment: The entire system app folder? No, that would have destroyed everything. But the app wasn't in it anymore.

Comment: No no, I didn't mean the entire system app folder . I meant the folder of the keyboard app — `/system/app/LatinIME` or `/system/app/LatinIMEGoogle` for AOSP Keyboard and GBoard, respectively. (However, the folders could have also been named differently based on the developer of the ROM)

Comment: I don't have a folder with either of those names, even with GBoard installed again now. I had originally looked for "GBoard".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the question, but I managed to work around it:

I had a backup of the app, restored that back to the system partition, then I was able to uninstall it with ADB (without `google.` in the package name) and install it again.

Comment: Ok. This is something different. `com.google.android.inputmethod.latin` and `com.android.inputmethod.latin` are 2 different apps. The one with 'google' in the package name is called GBoard/Google Keyboard whereas the latter one is called Android AOSP Keyboard. The GBoard app doesn't usually come pre-installed on open-source systems (you said that you have a Fairphone) whereas the GBoard is a part of Google Apps (you mentioned that you flashed GApps). However, it is also worth noting that it is not possible to have a phone with both these keyboards as system apps.

Comment: Maybe I now understand why GBoard crashes for you; there are 2 libraries of the names `libjni_latinimegoogle.so` and `libjni_keyboarddecoder.so` which are required by both, the AOSP Keyboard and the GBoard. The OpenGApps installer script shows that if GBoard is to be installed into the system, then a different version of these 2 files has to be put into the system and the AOSP Keyboard has to be removed. This doesn't seem to have happened in your case, and hence the crash. However, when GBoard is installed as a user app (non-system), it doesn't seem to need these 2 files to be in the system.

Comment: @ManasSambhus After a lot of back and forth I finally managed to install it as a user app. Still crashes in the preferences.

Comment: As soon as the app crashes, you can check the reason for the crash in the `/data/system/dropbox` folder. Sort the files by newest to oldest. Look for files that are named as `data_app_crash` or `system_app_crash`. However if these files happen to have a `.lost` extension, then you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Manas https://pastebin.com/6khqGpbw Googling that error message leads me to a two year old bug report on Github where the only advice seems to be a factory reset: https://github.com/opengapps/aosp_build/issues/116 But what I did was installing the OS, updating it and then installing Google apps, so I don't think another reset would help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

1. `pm uninstall com.google.android.inputmethod.latin`
2. `pm uninstall com.android.inputmethod.latin`
3. Removing `<renamed-package new="com.google.android.inputmethod.latin" old="com.android.inputmethod.latin" />`
   from `/data/system/packages.xml`
4. Reboot